# text file parsing and importing permuted result

Tags: python, parsing, numpy, text

I know the cvs module provides a very nice way to parse text files in python. I have a file that has the following columns:

```
x y z b
```

Here, x y z b are floating point numbers. However, I am faced with the possibility that the order right be permuted in any possible way. For example, it may be that the file comes as

```
b y x z
```

Now, I would like to read the data into a numpy array which should store the data in the b x y z format. So, the reading function should be something like:

```
def read_file(file_path, inputformat='xyzb', delimiter=' '):
```

Now, I could look at each line and have a big if/else kind of logic where for each of the four positions, I would query the format character and then insert it into the corresponding position in the array. However, I was wondering if there is more elegant way to take care of this permutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest loading the data using `numpy.loadtxt` (see [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)), then array-slicing to correct the column order.

**Edit:** actually, you can use the `usecols` parameter to directly specify the desired column order, like:

```
import numpy as np

def read_file(file_path, input_format="xyzb", desired_format="bxyz", delimiter=" "):
    usecols = [input_format.index(col) for col in desired_format]
    with open(file_path, "r") as inf:
        return np.loadtxt(inf, usecols=usecols, delimiter=delimiter)
```

Comment: This is great. I did not know this: I could so something like: i = np.array([0, 2, 3, 1]) and x = x[:, i] to permute the columns.